30 year swap yield vs the 30 year government bond yield?
I'm using bloomberg and see that the 30 year gov bond yield (around 4.4) is different from the 30 year sofr IRS (which is around 3.6).
Don't both of these measures represent annualized rate that I will pay/sell if were to buy/sell it? How can there be such a large difference?
Do these 2 assets represent something completely different?
